# Java libgdx camera.unproject() not syncing with batch.draw()

Tags: java, libgdx

I am programming a 2d platformer with libgdx, I'm trying to make a menu screen where the player can click a button and it will load that level.  I use gdx.input for the click coordinates and TextureRegion.getRegionX() for the button coordinates. They don't sync together and I read that camera.unproject should fix this problem. I duly used it but the coords still don't match. camera.unproject seems to set 0,0 for x and y as the centre of the screen, while batch.draw (which is the method which draws the TextureRegion to screen) seems to be using the bottom left hand corner as x and y's 0, 0.

Here is the code, I left out what I didn't think was relevant:

```
public class LevelScreen implements Screen {

private TextureRegion level_bg;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Camera camera;  
private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
private TextureRegion lockselectbg[]=new TextureRegion[10];

public LevelScreen(){               
}   

@Override
public void show() {

    batch=new SpriteBatch(); 
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(500,700);   

    LevelStatus.put();
    LevelStatus.get();      
    textureAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("levelatlas.pack"));
    Array<AtlasRegion> atlasArrays = new Array<AtlasRegion>(textureAtlas.getRegions());     
    level_bg = atlasArrays.get(0);

    lockselectbg[0] = atlasArrays.get(21);
    }

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(159/255.0f,220/255.0f,235/255.0f,0xff/255.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();      
    batch.draw(level_bg, -500/2,-348/2);
    batch.draw(lockselectbg[0], -180,0);
    batch.end();

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
       Vector3 tmp = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
       camera.unproject(tmp);
       Rectangle textureBounds = new Rectangle(lockselectbg[0].getRegionX(), lockselectbg[0].getRegionY(), lockselectbg[0].getRegionWidth(), lockselectbg[0].getRegionHeight());
       if(textureBounds.contains(tmp.x, tmp.y)) {
            System.out.println("It worked");
       }
     }
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    textureAtlas.dispose();
    batch.dispose();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Camera#unproject` will convert touch coordinates to world coordinates. They have nothing to do with the location of the region on the texture, which is what `TextureRegion` is. You are practically comparing world (read: game logic) coordinates with asset coordinates. Those two are completely unrelated.

If you want to check whether your image on the screen is touched then compare the touch coordinate with the location and size of the image you used in the `batch.draw` call. For example:

```
float x = -180f;
float y = 0f;
float width = 200f;
float height = 150f;
...
batch.draw(region, x, y, width, height);
...
camera.unproject(tmp.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
boolean touched = tmp.x >= x && tmp.y >= y && tmp.x < (x + width) && tmp.y < (y + height);
if (touched)
    System.out.println("It worked");
```

Btw, you might want to read this post: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels as well, because you are coupling your logic with asset size.

Comment: This didn't work either. It seems to be doing the same thing as before, in fact I don't really see the difference from what I had to what you had.

Comment: Did you actually read the answer? What exactly don't you see?

Comment: I used your code in my project and I got the same result. In your answer, you convert the Gdx.Input coords using camera.unproject, which is the same thing I did, the only difference is that I used a Rectangle and .contains  for the button coords but you use a boolean.

Comment: No, you didn't use the button coords, you used the region coords, which are two very different things. Perhaps read the answer again and *don't* look only at the code which I've included as *example*.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, I see what you probably meant now. Thanks for trying to help.